# Fetching of the Columns and Rows using Database name over Schema Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to achieve finding the number of rows in a given column, I understand that we can achieve that by doing something like

```
   SELECT DISTINCT s.name as SchemaName,OBJECT_NAME(o.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,p.row_count
FROM 
SYS.objects o JOIN SYS.schemas s
         ON o.schema_id=s.schema_id
              JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats p
         ON o.object_id=p.object_id
WHERE o.type LIKE 'U' 
AND s.name LIKE '%dbo%'   -- schema name
ORDER BY TableName
```

However I could not find a join between the Sys.Databases and the aforementioned query. Suggestions? Or is there any efficient way to achieve the same?

Comment: **Number of rows in a given column = number of rows in a given table**. Each column has the same "amount of rows", it can have `NULL` instead of a value, but this doesn't disqualify a row. You shouldn't actually say "number of rows in a column" - there's no such thing.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What result are you trying to get?

Comment: Okay thank-you for pointing that out, using sql server.

Comment: I want to pass the name of the db and get the aforementioned details, rather than passing the name of the schema

Comment: Are you trying to pass in the database name as a parameter? If so this requires dynamic sql because you need to execute the above query against the system tables for that database.

Comment: @SeanLange yes I am going to pass the database name as a parameter but I got stuck to the point where I could not find any join between the sys.database and sys.schema to achieve that

Comment: You can't join those. It logically doesn't work. sys.objects is the objects in the current database. sys.databases is a listing all databases on the instance.

Comment: You can't join Sys.Databases, you should run USE dbname and then run your query. So it can be sort of dynamic query over your databases using your own method or sp_MSforeachdb or something similar.